# Return Linq query results into List object

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am trying to return the results of a query into a List object, however the following code, as I normally use, does not work. Still relatively new to Linq, can someone explain the correct syntax/what's going on? This will work if I change the data type of `productTraining` to `var`...

```
List<AgentProductTraining> productTraining = new List<AgentProductTraining>();  

productTraining = from records in db.CourseToProduct
                  where records.CourseCode == course.CourseCode
                  select records;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Select()` and `Where()` will return `IQueryable<T>`, not `List<T>`. You've got to convert it to a `List<T>` - which actually executes the query (instead of just preparing it).

You just need to call `ToList()` at the end of the query. For example:

```
// There's no need to declare the variable separately...
List<AgentProductTraining> productTraining = (from records in db.CourseToProduct
                                              where records.CourseCode == course.CourseCode
                                              select records).ToList();
```

Personally I wouldn't use a query expression though, when all you're doing is a single `Where` clause:

```
// Changed to var just for convenience - the type is still List<AgentProductTraining>
var productTraining = db.CourseToProduct
                        .Where(records => records.CourseCode == course.CourseCode)
                        .ToList();
```